# How would I allow multi-line text editing in Windows Forms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am relatively new to using C# Windows Forms. However, I really wanted to create an application similar to Notepad++ so that I could practice. Most of what I have coded so far has not been overly complex, however this one issue still bothers me.

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is allowing vertical text selection. In programs such as Notepad++ you are able to hold down on `Ctrl+Shift` and then press the arrow keys to select vertically. This also allows the user to type on multiple selected lines at the exact same time. My question is, does anyone know how to go about doing this in C# with Windows Forms?

Inserted below is a picture that represents exactly what I am referring to.
[image]

Comment: You can do it even in WIn Forms by default.
Btw I suggest you to use 'RichTextBox'es instead of 'TextBox'es if you need to edit multiline text

Comment: @FilippoFerrario I do not believe that a RichTextBox supports vertical selection of text. I will go ahead and post a picture of what I mean by vertical text selection so that it is not confused by anyone. I already have the TextBox set to multiline, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Neither a Textbox nor a RichTextBox will allow multiple non-contiguous selections, let alone editing. But a RTB will let you highlight any portions, so you can simulate the selection part. The editing part you need to clearly define; then you may be able write code for it..

Comment: You  need to use a Courier Font so characters are fixed width.

Comment: Yup any fixed font will do but will also be necessary..

Comment: I already have a fixed font picked out. I am mainly asking if anyone knows any nice way to implement this. This includes needing to extend the TextBox class if needed.

Comment: "Extending the TextBox" is far from enough if your goal is to mimic a full feature editor like Notepad++ or VS Code. SharpDevelop 3.x is WinForms based and can serve a complete sample for your reference, https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Release-History (Its 4.x/5.x releases are WPF based.)